# Best way to facilitate Pi to Pi communication with no network?

Tags: networking, ssh, led, python-2.x

I have written two python scripts. One which drives an LED matrix and displays a message based on which argument(digits 0-5) you pass when you call the script. The script parses the number and selects the message to display from a dictionary. My other script is hooked up to an electrical near field sensor that captures directional gestures (swipes from north to south, east to west... etc) and then uses if elif statements to decide which argument to we will be passing onto the LED display. The reason why its not all in one script is because the gesture sensor takes all of my GPIO pins as it is a HAT.

The system I've built is intended to be used in my car where there is no network... So I'm currently at a loss trying to figure out how I can establish communication between the two machines.

So, what is the best way with no wifi network to SSH or get the ability to call one script on one pi from another script on a different pi?

Comment: What model Pi's are you using?

Comment: Two Pi 3 model b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few options:

- Assign the two Pi's static IP addresses and connect them using an ethernet cable. The Pi Foundation has a series of [lessons](https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/networking-lessons/lessons/) on doing this.
- Create a [WiFi access point](https://learn.adafruit.com/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-wifi-access-point/overview) on one of the Pi's.
- Use a pair of USB to TTL devices like this [one](https://www.banggood.com/FT232RL-FTDI-USB-To-TTL-Serial-Converter-Adapter-Module-For-Arduino-p-917226.html) and connect their rx and tx pins (rx of one to the tx of the other). This [tutoriual](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-5-using-a-console-cable/overview) uses a console cable (which won't work with a hat, but the concept is the same).